# Liferay: get attribute in processAction which is set during rendering phase in portletRequest

Tags: liferay-6

Liferay: how to get attribute in processAction which is set during rendering phase in portletRequest?

Edited:

What I'm trying to do -

Rendering phase : I'm building a list of element and populating it to PortletAttributes through setAttribute(key, value) method.

Now I'm able to see my data at jsp in tabular form and I do some changes on jsp. On page submission, I'm having call in my custom processAction menthod ->> Now what I want to see modified list on jsp in my action.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access attributes in the action phase, I think the easiest solution would be to use the portlet session. In rendering phase :

```
renderRequest.getPortletSession().setAttribute("attr", objects, PortletSession.PORTLET_SCOPE);
```

In your action :

```
actionRequest.getPortletSession().getAttribute("attr", PortletSession.PORTLET_SCOPE);
```

Comment: Hey Thanks, mate :) I'm following the same approach but was thinking to have some other way. Cheers!